# Как сделать темные темы к автодокументации в FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger

Тупой вопрос, возможно меня сейчас заминусуют, но я действительно не нашел в интернете ничего что могло бы помочь

У меня есть авто-документация, но, я хочу прикрутить к ней темную тему, я нашел решение только для swagger (очень некрасивое но хотябы нашел)

```
@app.get("/docs", include_in_schema=False)
async def custom_swagger_ui_html_cdn():
    return get_swagger_ui_html(
    openapi_url=app.openapi_url,
    title=f"{app.title} - Swagger UI",
    # swagger_ui_dark.css CDN link
    swagger_css_url="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Itz-fork/Fastapi-Swagger-UI-Dark/assets/swagger_ui_dark.min.css"
)
```

Но а как там дела с redoc'ом?

И вообще, как правильно такое в боевых проектах обычно делают?